# PHP entering data as 0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using namecheap hosting with their database of course. I am using PDO in order to insert the data.

```
$uid = $db->lastInsertId();
$insertColors = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO user_colors (user) VALUES (?)');
$insertColors->bindValue(1, $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insertColors->execute();
```

each time a user signs up to my website they are assigned an ID through here.
The errors I've gotten lead me back to this line of code (above all the other code)

> ```
> $insert->execute();
> ```

line 114

heres the rest of that code.

```
$insert = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username, `password`, email, ip, bday, bmonth, byear, timelastseen, timeregistered) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$insert->bindValue(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindValue(2, password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindValue(3, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindValue(4, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindValue(5, substr($_POST['bdate'], 1, 1), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insert->bindValue(6, substr($_POST['bdate'], 3, 3), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insert->bindValue(7, substr($_POST['bdate'], 6, 7), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insert->bindValue(8, time(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insert->bindValue(9, time(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insert->execute();
```

Comment: Which data is entered as `0`?

Comment: Can you please share the value of $uid and the structure of user_colors?